Scrollable resizable div with fixed button
The following HTML shows a scrollable resizable div with a button and a further content div in it.


.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: lightgray;
}

.container .fixed {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
<div class="container">
  <button class="fixed">Test</button>
  <div class="content">
    texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
  </div>
</div>



The button should be fixed at the top right corner in the div. This works fine for resizing, however, when I scroll, the button moves too. How can I fix this?

I initially misunderstood the pinning of the button.  Anyway, the following works.  You can resize the div and the button stays in the top right corner. [Edit] - So because the two elements are decoupled, I don't believe CSS can do it, so I added a little bit of JS to finish the job.  It's crude but effective, and you can expand on this.


const resizer = new ResizeObserver((items) => {
    items.forEach(item => {
        const btn = document.getElementById("content-button-id");
        btn.style["right"] = item.target.clientHeight < item.target.scrollHeight ? "25px" : "5px";
    })
});
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const el = document.getElementById("content-id");
    resizer.observe(el);
});
.container {
    position: relative;  /* Required for inner absolute position */
    height: 150px;
    resize: both; /* overflow is required to accompany this */
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex; /* use flex box to fill vertical spaces */
    flex-flow: column;
}

.container .content {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: lightgray;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 5;
}

.container .content-button {
    position: absolute; /* pin to outer container */
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Resize Component Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button id="content-button-id" class="content-button">Test</button>
        <div id="content-id" class="content">
            <p>
            texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            </p>
            <p>
                texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            </p>
            <p>
                texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            </p>
            <p>
                texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            </p>
            <p>
                texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            </p>
            <p>
                texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            </p>
            <p>
                texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            </p>
            <p>
                texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



Some screenshots of it in action



This doesn't work. When I resize the div, the button just stays where it is and thus it is no longer in the top right corner of the div.

I tested this, and it does work, the button moves if you resize, and when the slide bar moves it also persists.   What browser did you try this on?  I tried Chrome and Edge

I've tested on Edge (and now on Chrome again with the same result). Can you insert a code snipped in your answer (as I did in my question now), showing that it works?

@stonar96 Here you go, apologies for the delayed response.

Thanks, it works fine. When inserting a few lines of text, the vertical scroll bar appears and is partially covered by the button. Do you think it's also possible to move the button slightly to the left, depending on whether the vertical scroll bar is visible? (This also worked in the example in my question. I've removed my -1 and gave it a +1 now. I'd accept this as the ultimate answer if you can also solve the problem described in this comment.)

It's not pure CSS but it does the trick.

You should move the style overflow: auto inside the content class.
Also, adjust the content class to have a height of 100% if you intend to scroll inside container div, if not you can remove height: 100% and scroll within the content itself.


.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: lightgray;
}

.container .fixed {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}

.container .content{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
<div class="container">
  <button class="fixed">Test</button>
  <div class="content">
    texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
  </div>
</div>




When doing this, the container isn't resizable anymore.
